# Problem with longtblr not breaking inside tabular

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabularray

As you may have noticed in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682817/how-to-automatically-adjust-the-table-width-to-fit-the-page/682819) post, I am having trouble adjusting `tblr` to fit the page width. Zarko suggested that it might be a bug and recommended using `tabularx` instead. I tried placing the `tabular` inside `longtblr`, but I encountered a problem: the `longtblr` does not break inside the `tabular`, which generates a lot of vertical space between the second and third row, as shown in the image.

Zarko also suggested that I provide information about the size of my images. However, my images are in PDF format, so I am unsure if the concepts of width and height apply. I would like to continue using the `longtblr` package for my table, as it is a long table and I don't have enough time to switch to a new package at the moment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{colortbl}
   \usepackage{cellspace,   % for adding vertical space around cells' contents
                tabularx}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{0pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{1pt}
\newcommand\mcxx[1]{\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\linewidth=\hsize}X @{}}{#1}}
\newlength\colwidth

\begin{document}
\lipsum[]
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}

\onecolumn
\begin{longtblr}{
  width=\textwidth,
  cells = {c},
  hlines,
  colspec= {|c| X[c,m]}
}
1 & X \\
2 & y \\
3 & {\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\settowidth\colwidth{Coefficient}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\centering}p{\colwidth} *{2}{SX} @{}}
    \toprule
C1 & C2 & C3\\
    \midrule
Normalized Coefficient 
    & \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-a}   & \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-b} \\
   \midrule
$A$ & \mcxx{\includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image}}  \\
   \midrule
$B$ & \mcxx{\includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image}}  \\
   \arrayrulecolor{blue}
   \bottomrule[3pt]
\end{tabularx}}

\end{longtblr}


\end{document}
```

Update:

I tried the solution by @Jasper Habicht  with a different data but it does  not work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength\colwidth
\settowidth\colwidth{Coefficient}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn

\begin{longtblr}{
  colspec = { c Q[c,wd=\colwidth] *{2}{X[c,m]} },
  width = \textwidth,
  hlines,
  vlines,
  cell{1-2}{2} = {c=3}{},
  cell{3}{1} = {r=4}{},
  cell{5-Z}{3} = {c=2}{},
}
1 & X & & \\
2 & y & & \\
3 & C1 & C2 & C3 \\
  & Normalized Coefficient 
    & \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l]Q[c]Q[r]},rowspec={|Q[t]|Q[m]|Q[b]|}}
{Alpha \\ Alpha} & Beta & Gamma \\
 Delta & Epsilon & {Zeta \\ Zeta} \\
 Eta & {Theta \\ Theta} & Iota \\
\end{tblr}
    &\includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-a}  \\
  & $A$ 
    & \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-b} & \\
  & $B$ 
    &  & \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tabularx` forms a single box and can't be broken across pages, nesting that single box inside a structure that itself can be broken across pages will not change the nature of the nested box.

Comment: @Skillmon Do you have a solution to this? I am desperate. The problem suddenly occurred as a bug, and I don't have enough time to study and try a different type of long table at this time.

Comment: Hm, why do you want the images inside a table? Why can't the images be smaller? What will it look like in the end, i.e. once you achieved what you're after?

Comment: @MS-SPO I have a `longtblr` with some rows containing images, nested `tblr`, and other elements. While reducing the size of the images could be a solution, it may not necessarily solve the problem of spurious vertical space, as Zarko mentioned in the linked post.

When I achieve the desired outcome, the table would resemble the image I posted above, but without any vertical space issues. Ideally, I would like the long table to break at any row.

Comment: Hm I just have an idea, can I just make every row `tabularx` so it can break anywhere instead of combining three rows into one like that so it cannot beak?

Comment: Give it a try. // I mean: what's the purpose of tables here? Is it just to positiong drawings? Has it any visual value for communicating your message? What would you do, if tables weren't available in LaTeX for some reason?

Comment: @MS-SPO It is an appendix where I include all the results with mathematics, smaller tables, images, and other relevant information.

Comment: Hm, still don't get, why tables are needed for the images. // Would packages image-gallery be useful for you? https://ctan.org/pkg/image-gallery // What's about package miniplot? https://ctan.org/pkg/miniplot

Comment: @MS-SPO it looks similar but I like to have more control on that. I want to customize for every row as well so I can place anything I want. Also I want a table with caption etc.

Comment: sorry but why on earth are you using for such a simple tabular with three columns two complicated packages like tabularray and tabularx? A longtable and a bit of manual calculation to set the width of the columns should be quite enough (and if you insist on tabularray you can calculate the width and use it there too).

Comment: As I worn you in comment to my answer (which use here in question). you will faced with new problems. I don't understand why you nest tables when use just one would be far more appropriate. BTW, if you use my code, than it would be nice, if you accept my answer ...

Comment: Hm, why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't things be much easier without nesting different tabular environments, for example like this:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newlength\colwidth
\settowidth\colwidth{Coefficient}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn

\begin{longtblr}{
  colspec = { c Q[c,wd=\colwidth] *{2}{X[c,m]} },
  width = \textwidth,
  hlines,
  vlines,
  cell{1-2}{2} = {c=3}{},
  cell{3}{1} = {r=4}{},
  cell{5-Z}{3} = {c=2}{},
}
1 & X & & \\
2 & y & & \\
3 & C1 & C2 & C3 \\
  & Normalized Coefficient 
    & \includegraphics[valign=m, width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics[valign=m, width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
  & $A$ 
    & \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image} & \\
  & $B$ 
    & \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image} & \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

In your edit you discovered a feature that I was not aware of up to now: The column type of the last column of a nested tabular seems to affect the position of this tabular in its parent cell. I currently don't know why this is, but (as a probably somewhat hacky workaround) you can add `\hfill` before and after the nested tabular to center the nested tabular in its cell.

Also, to simplify things as for calculating the widths of the columns, I would suggest that you do not use `X` columns for the two right columns but instead use fixed widths. This way, you (and the package) can easier calculate the width of spanning cells:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength\colwidth
\settowidth\colwidth{Coefficient}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn

\begin{longtblr}{
  colspec = { X Q[c,wd=\colwidth] *{2}{Q[c,m,wd=7.25cm]} },
  width = \linewidth,
  hlines,
  vlines,
  cell{1-2}{2} = {c=3}{},
  cell{3}{1} = {r=4}{},
  cell{5-Z}{3} = {c=2}{},
}
1 & X & & \\
2 & y & & \\
3 & C1 & C2 & C3 \\
  & Normalized Coefficient & 
\hfill \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l]Q[c]Q[r]}, rowspec={|Q[t]|Q[m]|Q[b]|}}
{Alpha \\ Alpha} & Beta & Gamma \\
 Delta & Epsilon & {Zeta \\ Zeta} \\
 Eta & {Theta \\ Theta} & Iota \\
\end{tblr} \hfill
    &\includegraphics[valign=m,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
  & $A$ 
    & \includegraphics[valign=m,width={\dimexpr14.5cm+2\tabcolsep}]{example-image-b} & \\
  & $B$ 
    & \includegraphics[valign=m,width={\dimexpr14.5cm+2\tabcolsep}]{example-image-b} & \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I actually did this at the begining but then I converted it to two columns as the number of rows with merge is a lot. Anyways, I'll give it a try then.

Comment: @hana You may need to merge a lot of cells, but as you can see in my example, the `tabularray` package provides a syntax that makes it relatively easy to set this up.

Comment: Yeah, I attempted to create the table yesterday and found it simple to make the first three rows. However, copying and pasting didn't work easily for the remaining rows. I was wondering if inserting a space in the setting on top would cause an error, for example, `\longtblr{ hlines, (some vertical space here), vlines}`?

Comment: @hana You should only use the proper syntax for adding options here. Check the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf).

Comment: Do you know a fix for the issue I just updated in the original post?

Comment: @hana Why don't you just post what you want to achieve eventually? Now you again try to nest tabulars. And you don't explain what does "not work". Add `width=\linewidth` to the image to restrict it to the cell width. Use `X` column types to stretch the nested tabular to the width of the cell,

Comment: If you look at the update post above, there are some problems with it. 1. The table in the column C2 is not aligned correctly although I already set it to center align. 2. The image below C3 does not fit the cell. I tried `width=\linewidth` but the table is still too big that causes overfull.

Comment: @hana I think, it might be better to ask a new question where you exactly show what you want to achieve. For me adding `width=\linewidth` works nicely. As for the alignment of the tabular, I have to admit that I am not sure why this is. But you could add `\hfill` before and after as a (admittedly somewhat hacky) workaround. Nesting tabulars using the `tabularray` package is sometimes a bit tricky, because this package uses mutiple cycles to adjust and calculate the cell heights and widths (which is why I tried to come up with a solution that does not need nesting in the beginning).

Comment: Could we have a chat somewhere here? I want to see how it work on your side. Also I wonder if you could help post the issue to the package creator? I tried some day ago but I'm new to LaTeX so probably I didn't make it clear, there was no reply so I deleted it. Also do you have experience with `longtable`? I wonder if it also has this issues. I don't think I can avoid nested tables as it's almost impossible for me to do it without nesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145414/discussion-between-jasper-habicht-and-hana).